# AWS RDS multi master writes in multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, high-availability, multi-master-replication

Is it possible to have something similar to DynamoDB global tables in AWS RDS?

I know that with Aurora we can have multiple read-replicas in different regions and two active masters in the same region but does AWS offer the possibility for a relational database to have two active masters to write to in two different regions?

Answer (score 1):

**No, that's not supported.**

Latency also makes this very difficult to achieve since you need to guarantee strong consistency, which is not the case with DynamoDB and its last-writer-wins model.